# What is the right Update Statement in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My original update statement is still working great in Sybase (see below) but we're migrating to Oracle 11g and I have to convert this update statement into Oracle Update.
I tried so many version and keep getting error, I guess I have not gotten a grib of how Oracle Update statement works. Can anyone help?

My original good Update Statement (in Sybase):

```
UPDATE Valid
    SET A.status = 'X',
        A.reason = 'Missing'
  FROM Valid A, Valid B
  WHERE A.id_number = B.id_number
  AND A.session_id = 69
  AND A.userid = 'BS'
  AND A.status = 'A' 
  AND isnull(B.street1, ' ') = ' '
```

Below is my Oracle version that is not working no matter what I did:

```
MERGE
  INTO um_valid Target
  USING (select * from um_valid) SOURCE
  ON (t1.id_number = t2.id_number)                
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
   SET status = 'X',
       reason = 'Missing (street 1)'
  WHERE Target.session_id = 69
  AND Target.userid = 'BS'
  AND Target.status = 'A' 
  AND NVL(SOURCE.street1, ' ') = ' ')
```

The error I'm getting:
`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause at the end isn't appropriate. Maybe you need this:

```
MERGE
   INTO um_valid Target
   USING (
      select distinct id_number 
      from um_valid 
      where street1 is null
   ) SOURCE
   ON (
      Target.id_number = SOURCE.id_number
      AND Target.session_id = 69
      AND Target.userid = 'BS'
      AND Target.status = 'A' 
   )                
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
      status = 'X',
      reason = 'Missing (street 1)'
```

Comment: I tried it and now I got a diferent error:ORA-00904: "SOURCE"."STREET1": invalid identifier. The column name is STREET1

Comment: Are you sure it is STREET1? Do a Describe. Is it displayed in upper case? If not, match the case and surround by double quotes. Example:"street1" Can you select STREET1 from um_valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal update statement. Merge is for bulk operations.
If you need to update something when it exists or insert when it doesn't then you can use a merge statement.
So for your example try using the following:

```
UPDATE Valid
SET status = 'X',
    reason = 'Missing'
WHERE session_id = 69
AND userid = 'BS'
AND status = 'A' 
AND street1 is null
```

The above statement will update all rows in table "Valid" where session_id equals 69, userid equals BS, status equals A and street1 is empty (null).

I think this is what you need, if this is not the case pls let me know why you join valid with valid. The I will adjust my update.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
UPDATE Valid a
    SET status = 'X',
        reason = 'Missing'
  WHERE A.session_id = 69
  AND A.userid = 'BS'
  AND A.status = 'A' 
  AND exists (select null
              from   valid b
              where  a.id_number = b.id_number
                 AND coalesce(B.street1, ' ') = ' ')
```